# Can't use created module

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm trying to use a module that I created but I am getting the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException: Module (User) could not be initialized
```

Here is my module.php file:

```
<?php

namespace User;

class Module
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
    }
}
```

And here is my module.config.php file:

```
<?php

namespace User;

use 
    Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory
;

return 
[
    'controllers' => 
    [
        'factories' => 
        [
            Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
    'router' => 
    [
        'routes' => []
    ],
    'view_manager' => 
    [
        'template_path_stack' =>
        [
            __DIR__ . '/../view'
        ]
    ]
];
```

I have even used the starter module files that the Zend Framework provides but I am still getting the error, this is my first time using the new skeleton application. If I remove the user module the application works fine.

Comment: some questions: is the file called `module.php` or `Module.php`? Where is your `Module.php` located? What is your `module_paths` configuration value in `application.config.php`?

Comment: The file is named Module.php and is located inside the module's src folder as it is in the skeleton application and the module_paths are the default ones set in the skeleton application on github.

Comment: Did you registered module in a `application.config.php` in a array `modules` ?

Comment: Did you setup composer autoloading for your new module? Otherwise ZF will not know where to find the module class.

Comment: Yes the module is registered and is the autoloading not setup already with in the skeleton like ones before it?

Comment: No, you need to configure the composer autoloader for your new namespace (in the `composer.json`) and dump the updated autoloader (`composer dumpautoload`)